# In how many ways can 3 women and 4 men sit in a line if the women always sit together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can $3$ women and $4$ men sit in a line if the women always sit together?

$W W W M M M M$

So we take women as a one we have 5!

Then why do we multiply by $3!$? I can't understand it what's the logic? Where do we get the $3!$ from? Why can't we plus the $5!$ and $3!$?
Can anyone represent this visually ?

Comment: You have 5! ways to seat the four men + group-of-3-women. And then, for each of those ways, there are 3! ways to arrange the women. They are not always seated in the same order.

Comment: Can you represent this visually?

Comment: You have written $4!+1!=5!$. Surely you don't mean this. Please edit so it says what you actually mean.

Comment: I do mean this. 1! from the women 4! from the men

Comment: But 4! + 1! = 1*2*3*4 + 1 is not equal to 5! = 1*2*3*4*5.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still struggling with this problem. Can you show me how to solve this problem visually?please

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP insists that 4! + 1! = 5!.

Comment: Okay sorry changed it

Comment: You add when two events cannot occur simultaneously.  You multiply when two events can both occur.  In this case, we can arrange the four men and the block of women and we can arrange the women within the block, so we multiply.

Answer (score -1):

There is www mmmm, m www mmm, mm www mm, mmm www m, mmmm www

0 1 2 3 4 males in front for a total of 5 ways

If there are 4 males and 3 females the total permutations are

_ * _ * _ *  _ *  _ *  _  *_

If you consider each man and woman a separate person permutation then from above
www mmmm, m www mmm, mm www mm, mmm www m, mmmm www

3!*4! , wwwmmmm

4 * 3! * 3! = 4! * 3!,  m www mmm

4 * 3 * 3! * 2 * 1 = 4! * 3!, mm www mm

4 * 3 * 2 * 3! * 1 = 4! * 3!, mmm www m

4! * 3! mmmm www

And you add those. There will be some unusual findings to simplify this into one step if you know more

As user bodydouble has said above taking the group of 3 women as 1 we have 4 men and 1 group so 5! Ways to seat them but each way has the women permutations inside of 3! So total of 5! * 3!

Or simply 5* 4! * 3! As seen above

Comment: Please consider adding MathJax to make your formulas coherent